# pretty url in yii2 not working

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, yii2

In web.php i have this

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        ],
    ],
```

apache for this folder configured like this php.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
AssignUserId alexzander alexzander
ServerName localhost

DocumentRoot /home/alexzander/Dropbox/study/3year/2/php/
<Directory /home/alexzander/Dropbox/study/3year/2/php/>
    # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on

    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

when I'm try to access `localhost/basic/images/list`

I get
 `The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.`

when I add index.php after basic it works 
 `localhost/basic/index.php/images/list`

How do i get pretty url working? I think appache rewrite rule is not working, but don't know why.

in error.log

```
[Thu Jun 02 20:46:13.811518 2016] [:error] [pid 25046] [client 127.0.0.1:52450] script '/home/alexzander/Dropbox/study/3year/2/php/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/basic/index.php/images/list
```

but this because document root in apache looking inside `/home/alexzander/Dropbox/study/3year/2/php/` I think that's ok

```
apache2ctl -M



AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_itk_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UrlManager..

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        ],
    ],
```

**For Apache server**

Then add a new file with name `.htaccess` or edit an existing file in your project folder (not in protected).

[image]

Then add this code below to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

This is working for me and removed the index.php.

**For Nginx Server**

Check the server block in Nginx configuration as following:

```
server{
    listen      8082;
    server_name yii2.dev;
    access_log logs/yii2.access.log;
    error_log logs/yii2.error.log error;
    root /home/admin/web/nginx/html/basic/web/;
    location / {
            index  index.html index.php;
            if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?r=$1 last;
            }
    }
}
```

You can read the official guide of Yii 2 for nginx server **[here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#recommended-nginx-configuration)**.

Comment: A .htaccess (hypertext access) file is a directory-level configuration it acts as a subset of the server's global configuration file (like one that i paste in question i named it php.conf) for the directory that they are in, or all sub-directories.

So I alredy have this settings in appache, since .htacces is just extension of general config

Comment: `localhost/basic/site/login` The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server, if I add index.php `localhost/basic/index.php/site/login` i get  yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Comment: now it works, I don't know why general apache config can't do this, it seems like some sort of magic, but it worked, thx.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. I did it the same way in Yii 1.1 and I was hoping it will work for Yii 2.

Comment: but it works only without `'urlFormat'=>'path'` I think it yii1 thing and it not supported on yii2 or smth, because with it i get UnknownPropertyException

Comment: @AsfandyarKhan Do you know why 'enablePrettyUrl' => true not working in ngnix?

Comment: For nginx server, you will have to do it in server block instead of htacess.