# Yii2 GET parameters in url rules

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I've the following configuration for my urlManager:

```js
[
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' =>false,
    'rules' => [
        'add?step=first'    =>  'advert/first',
        'add?step=second'   =>  'advert/second'   
],
```

So for example when I go to `add?step=second` it should run `advert/second` but it gives me 404 error. How to make it work?

Comment: I think it suppose to be "expected url" => "current url"

Comment: No, it should be  `'pattern' => 'the actual route'`

Comment: I had problems doing the same thing in the past. I do not believe you can put in ? in the pattern. My solution cannot be applied to you.

Comment: Check my answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598914/pretty-url-in-yii2-not-working/37612933

Answer (score 0):

Try this rules instead:

```
'<add:(step=first)>' => 'advert/first',
'<add:(step=second)>' => 'advert/second'
```